# GNUPLOT Illegal day of month

Tags: linux, time, format, gnuplot, cpu

I am trying to make a graph out of my `stat.dat` file containing:

```
----system---- ----total-cpu-usage---- ------memory-usage----- -net/total-
     time     |usr sys idl wai hiq siq| used  buff  cach  free| recv  send
22-04 16:44:48|  0   0 100   0   0   0| 162M 57.1M  360M 3376M|   0     0
22-04 16:44:58|  0   0 100   0   0   0| 161M 57.1M  360M 3377M| 180B  317B
```

And I have a `gnu.sh` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal png
set output "top.png"
set title "CPU usage"
set xlabel "time"
set ylabel "percentage"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
plot "stat.dat"  using 1:3 title "system" with lines, \
"stat.dat" using 1:2 title "user" with lines, \
"stat.dat" using 1:4 title "idle" with lines
```

When I run the gnu file I receive this error:

```
Could not find/open font when opening font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf", using internal non-scalable font
----system---- ----total-cpu-usage---- ------memory-usage----- -net/total...
stat.dat:1:"./gnu.sh", line 12: illegal day of month
```

Is anyone familiar with this error and any solution which would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing the first line of your data file, gnuplot encounters an illegal day of month.

You must somehow skip the first two lines of your data file before they are parsed. Using version 5.0 or 4.6.6 you can use the new `skip` option to achieve this. This skips a number of lines at the beginning of the data file without parsing them (as opposed to `every`, which can skip a number of lines *after* parsing, which would still give an error):

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set style data lines
set border back
plot "stat.dat" using 1:4 skip 2 lw 3 title "system", \
     "" using 1:3 skip 2 lw 3 title "user", \
     "" using 1:5 skip 2 lw 3 title "idle"
```

Note also, that your column counting is wrong. The date contains a white space, so that it counts for two columns when you refer to the following values.

Alternatively, if you don't have version 5.0 or 4.6.6, you can use an external tool like `tail` to skip the first two lines:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set style data lines
set border back
plot "< tail -n +3 stat.dat" using 1:4 lw 3 title "system", \
     "" using 1:3 lw 3 title "user", \
     "" using 1:5 lw 3 title "idle"
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to monitor a pid or one process with dstat?